# Error: Unable to set value of the property 'src': object is null or undefined and CSS Error: Error in parsing value for 'top', Declaration dropped

Tags: javascript, css

This is the JavaScript portion of my assignment website - it should display a dating ad and on interval move it around the screen, and at each interval it loads a new image

It will randomly move horizontally, but won't move vertically. This problem happens in Firefox - in IE it has no problem.

However in IE it won't iterate over the images, but it does in Firefox.

Could anyone tell me what's going on?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rotatingAd = new Array(3);
    var curPosition = 1;
    var screenWidth = 0;
    var screenHeight = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) 
    {
        rotatingAd[i] = new Image();

        rotatingAd[i].src = "AdDate" + i + ".gif";

    }
    function openOrderForm()
    {
        window.open("order.html");
    }



    function moveAd(){
    var leftPos = getRandomLeft();
    var topPos = getRandomTop();
    document.getElementById("AdDate").style.top = topPos; + "px";//this is where firefox says the css error is 

          document.getElementById("AdDate").style.left = leftPos + "px";
    if(curPosition == 3)
    {
        curPosition = 0;
    }
    document.AdDatePic.src = rotatingAd[curPosition].src;//this is where IE gets its null error from    
    curPosition++;

}

    function start(){
  screenWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
  screenHeight= document.body.clientHeight;
  //alert("width="+screenWidth + "height="+screenHeight)
 //setTimeout("moveAd()", 3000);
  setInterval("moveAd()", 2000);
}

    function getRandomLeft(){
     var lpos;
     lpos = Math.floor(Math.random()*(screenWidth -400));
     return lpos;
    }

    function getRandomTop(){
     tpos = Math.floor(Math.random()*(screenHeight - 135));
      return tpos;
    }
</script>
<body onload="start();">
<span id="AdDate" style="position:absolute; left:300px; top:300px;" >
  <img id="AdDatePic" src="AdDate0.gif" alt="picture of gopher"   />
</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Is this an exact copy and paste of your source?  You have a syntax error on the line with the comment about FireFox:  `topPos; + "px"`

Comment: yeah its a paste we have to use notepad++ so theres no syntax checking. however without the + px; i couldn't get the image to move at all

Comment: In addition to the syntax error, IE can act quite differently when running in `standards` or `quirks` mode.  What is your DOCTYPE and is it the very first line?

Comment: doctype is
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
and its first line IE says its running in quirks mode

Comment: Did you try correcting the syntax error?  `topPos; + "px"` should be `topPos + "px"`, without the semicolon

Comment: hmm i think you may be right i didnt see that lemme give it a shot

Comment: ah excellent thank you that fixed the up and down movement\

Comment: Making requests from same element repeatedly is rather inefficient.  You should cache your object via `var myImg = document.getElementById('AdDatePic')` instead of having `document.getElementById('AdDatePic')` calls all over the place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your issue with IE is related to how your trying to select the picture tag

changing your code to

`document.getElementById("AdDatePic").src`

from

```
document.AdDatePic.src
```

should fix the IE issue

The firefox issue is from semicolon placement

```
topPos + "px;"
```

should fix the issue

Comment: thanks for your help the document.getElementById("AdDatePic").src fixed my IE problem how ever IE was giving me an error with the "px;" inside the quotes, fixing the syntax error suggested by cimmanon worked perfect thanks to the both of you

Comment: Then you could just drop the ; altogether unless your applying multiple style attributes at once